# Is there any simple way to extract the key-value pairs from a JSON string for a given key using jackson libraries? (Java)

Tags: java, json

I have this json response:

```
{
  "Name": "tardis",
  "Driver": "custom",
  "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/tardis/_data",
  "Status": {
    "hello": "world"
  },
  "Labels": {
      "com.example.some-label": "some-value",
      "com.example.some-other-label": "some-other-value"
  },
  "Scope": "local"
}
```

From this response, I want to parse the key-value pairs inside "Labels" key. Currently my method to extract those looks like this:

```
            //"json" is the JSON response as a string
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(json);
            Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> it = root.fields();
            while (it.hasNext())
            {
                Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = it.next();
                JsonNode n = entry.getValue();
                String nlabel = entry.getKey();
                if (nlabel != null && nlabel.equals(key))
                {
                    Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> itr = n.fields();
                    while (itr.hasNext())
                    {
                        Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> it2 = itr.next();
                        String labelKey = it2.getKey();
                        String labelValue = it2.getValue().toString();
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
            }
```

I am able to retrieve those key value pairs using this logic, but I want to make it simpler because I want to make it work when there is a deeper nesting involved.
Is there a simpler, better way to do it using jackson libs?

Comment: Why don't you map the JSON to a Java class? That's what Jackson is about.

Comment: Do you mean I should create a Labels.java class? That won't work because the key field name should be fixed and in this case, it changes everytime.

Comment: No. The labels property of the class could be a Map<String, String>.

Comment: You have just solved my many many problems.